# Validate existence of a date in JavaScript (assuming proper formatting)

Tags: javascript, date

I am building a JavaScript and HTML widget that will reside on external webpages (via a copy/pasted snippet) and feed back into a rails application. I notice that JavaScript function `Date.parse("09/31/2014")` returns a number as if it's a real date (this year September only had 30 days), but when such a date hits the back end, rails rejects it (which can be demonstrated by running `"09/31/2014".to_date` in IRB).

I am looking for a solution that does not rely on external libraries, because as an embedded widget, I don't want to be loading tons of external resources into the host page.

Comment: http://javascriptkit.com/script/script2/validatedate.shtml is a free script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run Date.parse with the input in your example, javascript notices that you had too many days in September and overflows into October. The number returned is the timestamp for October 1st, 2014. You can tell this if you pass the number into the Date constructor to create a new Date object.

```js
var date = new Date(Date.parse("09/31/2014"));
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()); // "10/1/2014"
```

If that overflow is acceptable, then re-parsing the timestamp like this will allow you to write a function to correct the date in the string to a valid one. If that overflow is not acceptable and you simply need to validate the user input, and make them correct it, then you can easily enough check each component of the user string against the values of the re-parsed date object.

```js
function validateDateString(inputString) {
    var day, month, year,
        valid = false,
        dateRegex = /([\d]{1,2})\/([\d]{1,2})\/((?:[\d]{2}){1,2})/,
        searched = dateRegex.exec(inputString),
        dateObj = new Date(Date.parse(inputString));

    if (searched) {
        // If we're here, the date regex found a match
        // Assume date is valid until checks prove otherwise
        valid = true;

        month = parseInt(searched[1], 10);
        day = parseInt(searched[2], 10);
        year = parseInt(searched[3], 10);

        // Date object months are zero indexed
        if (month !== (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)) {
            valid = false;
        } else if (day !== dateObj.getDate()) {
            valid = false;
        } else if (year !== dateObj.getFullYear()) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}
```

The above function will return false for the invalid date input that you provided (I am assuming that the format of the date string will always be consistent), but will return true for a valid date string of the same format.

Comment: Perfect! And very thorough. Somehow I'd just been overlooking the fact that I could _output_ the parsed date and compare it.